# Any Downside to Backdoor Roth?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

Regardless of income, is there any reason *not* to do a back-door Roth if you can afford it?  Since you are paying tax on that income used for the contribution either way, it seems that there is only upside--all earnings on that Roth will be tax-free.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you talking about backdoor Roth IRA contribution vs. regular Roth IRA contribution? Or putting money in Roth IRA in general vs. in outside taxable accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some pitfalls to be aware of, as I recently found.  The irs does not distinguish between your different  Ira accounts when assessing taxes on conversions.  If, in addition to funding a traditional Ira with post-tax dollars, you have traditional ira's that were funded with pre-tax dollars, your conversion to Roth will create a taxable event for the pre-tax traditional accounts.  An often-cited example would be if you had an employer-sponsored retirement plan (401k for example) that was funded on a pre-tax basis, that you rolled over to a traditional Ira after you left that employer.  If this applies to you, I recommend further reading on the pro-rata rule.  If you don't have any pre-tax traditional iras, I am not aware of any issues with the backdoor Roth approach.  For more info -- https://www.kitces.com/blog/the-impact-of-the-ira-aggregation-rule-on-after-tax-distributions-roth-conversions-60-day-rollovers-rmds-and-72t-payments/.

Comment: Ugh, yeah.  I have other pre-tax IRAs that make this less than a perfect (i.e. tax-free) conversion.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote.  I actually went through the process of opening an IRA (plus one for my wife) and had a technical problem.  When I called the broker to correct it, the rep stopped me and explained the caveat of having ANY pre-tax IRAs from ANY year with ANY broker.  I thought she was crazy (and wrong), but then did my own research.  Situation 3 in this article explains it:  http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/042214/how-can-i-fund-roth-ira-if-my-income-too-high-make-direct-contributions.asp.  I am now doing a return of funds on those two IRAs.

Comment: There are some who worry that the IRS will retroactively deem backdoor Roth's as constructively a direct contribution via the "step transaction doctrine." Kitces also wrote about that: https://www.kitces.com/blog/dodging-the-income-limits-on-roth-contributions-strategy-or-abuse/

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your IRA contributions are non-deductible and you have no deductible portion - yes, you're right.